# Change instance attributes inside decorator

Tags: python, decorator, self

I have searched for this problem, but I did not find an answer to what I'm exactly looking for.

Basically, I want to wrap a class constructor in a try/except clause so it ignores specific types of errors inside the constructor (but logs and prints them anyway). The best way I have found to do this is to wrap my method with a decorator, since there are other classes in which I want to do the same, but I don't want to keep repeating the same try/except clauses.

However, **the object must remember whether an exception has happened in the constructor** (save it in a boolean attribute from that object) so that I can use that information later when that object calls a specific method later. So, I tried doing something like in this snippet:

```py
def detectAndIgnoreErrors(fn):
    def wrappedFunc(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
            self.HasAnExceptionOccurredInInit = False
        except KeyError as e:
            self.HasAnExceptionOccurredInInit = True
            # Log and print exception
        except RuntimeError as e:
            self.HasAnExceptionOccurredInInit = True
            # Log and print exception

    return wrappedFunc


class Foo(FooSuperclass):

    @detectAndIgnoreErrors
    def __init__(self):
        # Do stuff that may raise exceptions
        pass

    def doStuff(self):
        if self.HasAnExceptionOccurredInInit:
            # Do stuff
            pass
        else:
            # Do other stuff
            pass

fooInstance = Foo()
fooInstance.doStuff()
```

The idea here would be for the object to ignore errors in the constructor, and later when the `doStuff()` method is called, the object remembers whether an exception occurred or not with `HasAnExceptionOccurredInInit` and adjusts its behavior accordingly. However, the interpreter says that the `self` name is not defined (which makes sense, as I was trying to access it outside the class scope).

Then, I tried putting the decorator as a class member, and then later I tried putting it as a class member in Foo's parent class, but none of these alternatives worked.

After some research, I realized that decorators are resolved at definition time, not during execution time, so there's no way `self` can be used this way, so I don't know how I can solve this problem.

If someone knows how to solve this problem (or perhaps a better solution instead of decorators), it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrapped function doesn't have a parameter named `self`; you need to specify that specifically if you are going to assume `fn` is a method.

```
def detectAndIgnoreErrors(fn):
    def wrappedFunc(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.HasAnExceptionOccurredInInit = False
        except KeyError as e:
            self.HasAnExceptionOccurredInInit = True
            # Log and print exception
        except RuntimeError as e:
            self.HasAnExceptionOccurredInInit = True
            # Log and print exception

    return wrappedFunc
```